# Add new attribute HDFView with Array Size: Scalar instead of one

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I am trying to reverse engineer some data save in HDF5 files. Trying to understand the structure of the hdf5 file, to be able to create similar files -> to interact with a pipeline already build for this kind of files.

The pipeline kept on throwing the error:

```
TypeError: buffer size mismatch
```

I was copying and adding the atrributes using HDFView. But going through them, it looks like by adding attribute through HDFView -> selecting VLength -> and pasting the JSON string. I ended up with the attribute wrapped in an array [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWktH.png)

I think one of the errors can come from this, but how can I add the JSON attribute without the array() wrap?

Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't know what you've done with `HDFView`, but one of your files loads the attribute as a bytestring, the other loads a single element 1d object dtype array containing that string.   `.item()` or `[0]` should be able to extract that string from the array.  `h5py` is 'biased' toward interfacing as numpy arrays, but I'm not sure why there's a difference in these loads.

Comment: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html says that `attrs` values that it writes or modifies "Will be put through numpy.array(value)."

Comment: Thank you for the pointers @hpaulj

The 'Original', not numpy.array() is the one from the hdf5 file that I had.
The second one, in numpy.array() is the one where I added an attribute in HDFView: add atribute, datatype class: VLEN_String, and copied the json attribute.

My question is, how can i add this atribute as a bytesting element, and not with the numpy.array?

(I guess [0] would fix it. But I would prefer to find a workaround through the file. Instead of changing the program itself)
Thanks